# How do i get the recorded audio in steams in flutter?

Tags: flutter, azure

I'm trying to implement live transcript in flutter using azure cognitive speech services. I need to send the stream of audio data to azure using API. But I'm unable to get the streams using the record package.

is there any other package that needs to use?

To get the token and calling api

```
String authToken = '';

Future<void> fetchToken() async {
  String subscriptionKey = 'YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY';
  String region = 'YOUR_REGION';

  final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://$region.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken'),
      headers: {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey}
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    authToken = response.body;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to obtain authorization token: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}


String endpoint = 'https://YOUR_REGION.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1';
Uri uri = Uri.parse(endpoint);
Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'audio/wav',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $authToken',
};
Map<String, String> params = {
  'language': 'en-US',
  'format': 'simple',
  'profanity': 'masked',
  'recognitionMode': 'conversation',
};
Stream<List<int>> audioStream = getMicrophoneStream();
http.MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
  ..headers.addAll(headers)
  ..fields.addAll(params)
  ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromStream('audio', audioStream, contentType: MediaType('audio', 'wav')));
```

This is the recording code

```
Future<void> _start() async {
Directory? directory;
var status = await Permission.storage.status;
try {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    if (status.isGranted) {
      directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!;
      String newPath = "${directory.path}/Recordings";
      directory = Directory(newPath);
    } else {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
  } else {
    if (status.isGranted) {
      directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      String newPath = "${directory.path}/Recordings";
      directory = Directory(newPath);
    } else {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
  }
  if (!await directory!.exists()) {
    await directory.create(recursive: true);
  }
  if (await directory.exists()) {
    try {
      if (await _audioRecorder.hasPermission()) {
        final filePath =
            '${directory.path}/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.m4a';
        final isSupported = await _audioRecorder.isEncoderSupported(
          AudioEncoder.aacLc,
        );
        await _audioRecorder.start(path: filePath);
        _recordDuration = 0;
        _startTimer();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
}
```

Comment: Is there specific reason to use Azure Speech REST APIs on Android? Here is one example of Azure Speech SDK for Android, which uses Android AudioRecorder microphone stream as input to speech recognition https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/java/android/sdkdemo/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/cognitiveservices/speech/samples/sdkdemo/MainActivity.java#L151

Comment: @jhakulin I'm trying to integrate azure speech services into flutter and there is no flutter package that does the job. So I'm trying achieve it by send through REST api